# What is the improper integral of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x} \,dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

What is the improper  integral of  $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x} \,dx$$ 
a is between 0 and 1.

The result has to be pi/(sin(pi * a)) and is calculated somehow using Fourier series...

Comment: Are you sure that it's *indefinite* integral?

Comment: Yes, sure. I edited the integral. This is the final form of it which needs to be calculated. In my book the result is given: pi/(sin(pi * a)) , but I can't solve it

Comment: Do you know about residue theorem?

Comment: @KelemenNorbi I want to say, that this in fact isn't indefinite integral, it's definite integral. Whether a integral is definite or not is determined by whether it has upper and lower limits of not, respectively.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to write Improper integral, not Indefinite Integral

Comment: And I don't know about residue theorem....

Comment: Okay, can you at least add to your question in what course you have seen that integral and what kind of methods you know, your attempts etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we consider : $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$ => $ x=\frac{y}{1-y} \to  dx=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}dy$

and $y\to 0 $ as $x\to 0 $ and $y \to 1$ as $x \to \infty $

$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x}dx=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x}{1+x}.x^{a-2}dx=\int ^{1}_{0}y.(\frac{y}{1-y})^{a-2}\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}dy$

$=\int^{1}_{0}y^{a-1}.(1-y)^{(1-a)-1}dy=\beta(a,1-a)
$

$=\frac{\Gamma (a).\Gamma (1-a)}{\Gamma (a+1-a)}=\Gamma(a).\Gamma(1-a)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(a\pi)}$

---

[Euler's Reflection Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Reflection_Formula)

Comment: Thanks. This solution is great.

Comment: You are welcome :)